# How do I root Cubot z100?

Tags: rooting, 5.1-lollipop

I've seen some tools for the pc which say you just need to click a button and they'll give you root access, and I tried one of them, rootkhp, but I had no luck. If I recall correctly, when I rooted my last phone (Galaxy Mini 2 GT S6500) I needed to download some drivers, while this tool didn't tell me to do that. I did the 7 clicks on the kernel version to activate developer mode, I activated usb debugging, connected the phone to the pc and launched the program, clicked on root, it said something like "Your phone did verify, please wait" and after some time it said "Your phone successfully rooted, you can now close this notification". I closed it, closed the program, disconnected the pho e but I couldn't activate root only functions on my apps. I tried again after rebooting, no luck. Do you know how to root the Cubot Z100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are going for an automated one-click software, i would try one of these:

Kingo Root : kingoapp.com

King Root : kingroot.net (similar name, different developers)

iRoot : iroot.com

360Root : root.360.cn (this one is chinese only)

one of them should work, try one, uninstall, try other... good luck! if none of these work, i would wait more untill rooting your model becomes more known/common.

Also i found this page https://www.skyneel.com/cubot-usb-driver that seems to have USB drivers for your model